# CUPS not working correctly after Debian Wheezy -> Jessie upgrade because of a faulty libpam

Tags: debian, authentication, cups, pam, architecture

I just upgraded a Debian Wheezy to Jessie, by changing the `/etc/apt/sources.lst`. If important: I pinned `systemd` to stay with `sysvinit`, and after the upgrade I removed the pin. If I now do `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` everything is up to date. So far, everything works fine, only a problem with CUPS authentication arised:

On Wheezy there was already CUPS installed and worked, remote access was granted with `cupsctl --remote-admin`. I could authenticate on the web interface with `root:myrootpassword`. After the upgrade I did `cupsctl --remote-admin` again and it worked so that I can reach the admin web panel. Changing options still does require authentication, but using `root:myrootpassword` does not work anymore.

I looked up the logfile `/var/log/cups/error_log` which prints when trying to authenticate on the CUPS web interface:

```
pam_authenticate() returned 28 (Module is unknown)
```

Then I looked into `/etc/pam.d/cups`, which has:

```
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

These three included files exist in the same directory and are non-empty. I have however no experience with pam. These packages are installed:

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep  pam
libpam-cap:amd64                                install
libpam-ck-connector:amd64                       install
libpam-modules:amd64                            install
libpam-modules-bin                              install
libpam-runtime                                  install
libpam0g:amd64                                  install
libpam0g:i386                                   install
```

The file `/var/log/auth.log` has:

```
Apr 17 15:01:14 mypc cupsd: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_ck_connector.so): /lib/security/pam_ck_connector.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Apr 17 15:01:14 mypc cupsd: PAM adding faulty module: pam_ck_connector.so
```

However package `pam_ck_connector` is installed and latest version. Doing a `find / -name pam_ck_connector.so` gives:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_ck_connector.so
```

So it seems this files is simply in a wrong path. I tried setting a symbolic link, but then I get in `/var/log/auth.log` for this file:

```
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Then I installed The `i386` Package:

```
apt-get install libpam-ck-connector:i386
```

which installs to `/lib/i386[...]/security/libpam-ck-connector.so`. I set again a symbolic link. But then the same massage popped up for `pam_cap`. So, do we have some problem with 32<->64 Bit compatibility of some package (`libpam*` or `cups`) or a bug in Debian package manager/database? It can't be the correct way to have people install these things manually and set symbolic links, or is it?

**How can I fix this error message to make authentication work with `root:myrootpassword` again from the CUPS web panel?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you've ended up with `i386` `cups-daemon` installed, instead of `amd64`. That's why it ends up needing `i386` PAM modules...

To fix this, you need to remove `cups-daemon` and re-install the `amd64` version; as root:

```
apt-get remove cups-daemon:i386
apt-get install cups-daemon:amd64
```

If your `dpkg` architectures are set up correctly you should be able to drop the `:amd64` portion of the last command.

Comment: Thanks, there where some more packages existing as `i386`, but their `amd64` counterparts where there as well (only `cups` was 32 Bit-only without noticing that it missed dependent packages). I removed the `i386` packages alltogether. This hickhack must have happened on the Wheezy -> Jessie upgrade, because I installed a very slim headless, pure 64 Bit Wheezy originally.